# Why does my popup window lose its event beforeunload after a reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, window

I have a small application that opens a new popup. I store the window in a variable:

```
popup = window.open("sites/display.html", "_blank");
```

After that I add a beforeunload Eventlistener:

```
$(popup).on('beforeunload', function(){
    // Do something
});
```

I then later reload the window with a button:

```
popup.location = popup.location;
```

After that if I close the window the Event beforeunload isn't fired anymore. I think it has something to do with the reload because if I dont reload the page everything works fine.

How can I fix this so the event is fired everytime the window closes?

Exact code I use:

```
function startClock(allowRestart) {
    saveSettings(allowRestart);
    if ($("#separated-display").is(":checked")) {
        // Separated mode activated
        if (popup == undefined) {
            openPopup();
        } else {
            if (popup.closed) {
                openPopup();
            }else{
                popup.location.reload();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Separated mode deactivated
        if (popup != null && popup.closed == false) {
            $(popup).unbind();
            popup.close();
        }
        window.location = "sites/display.html"; // Open the clock in same window
    }
}

function openPopup(){
    // Open new popup window
    popup = window.open("sites/display.html", "_blank");

    // TO-DO: Fix event not fired after 1. window reload 2. window close
    popup.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){
        console.log("unload");
    });
}
```

Comment: Look in the console. I am sure you get an error like "access from ... denied"

Comment: Actually everything works. There is no error in the console. Its a popup with one of my html files so the same-origin policy is fulfilled.

Comment: Are you trying to open a window of the same domain or is it cross-origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're trying to access the same origin (with the relative path) window using `window.open()`, Access error shouldn't be displayed.

```
popup = window.open("/sites/display.html", "_blank")
```

`popup` variable would refer to the newly created window which is a thin wrapper representing a `WindowProxy` object, which indeed has all features of `window` available.

When the page reloads everything is set to default, and the window loses its properties set before. Therefore, the `unload` event attached earlier is not anymore attached. This would happen for other events as well.

Hence the problem here that the event is being attached to the popup window just once on opening the popup, which is reset on page reload. The best way to go forward would be to add the `unload` event in the js file which loads specifically on `sites/display.html` page. There, every time when `sites/display.html` page loads you could access the new window object and attach events in `window.load / document.ready` (according to your use case).

You won't able to attach the event to pop up before or after invoking page reload as you're doing it currently as, the property would be reset if you try setting it before/after page reload as it might be executed asynchronously.

NOTE:

1. You should rather use the `reload()` function exposed by `window.location` instead of updating the location property. As updating the property doesn't skip browser cache.

```
popup.location.reload()
```

2. The support for `window.open` is [unknown for most browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=window.open), though I was able to use it on `Chrome 84`.

Comment: Are you getting all the values right? 1. Does popup have the reference to the window object? 2. Are you able to attach the event? 3. Are you using the reload function as assigning into location won't work here?

Comment: No it doesn't work even with your answer. I add some code to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I now have another problem: how can I use functions that are only available in the main window (not popup)? can I use window.opener? or how can I solve this?

Comment: Attach main window specific events/properties in the js file where main window is being referenced. The basic rule to follow is to keep page-specific actions on that page which could be reattached on reload.  You can pass messages between tabs using inter-tab communication, you could use local storage/cookies for it.

Comment: You can even use `Broadcast Channel API` for communication between windows, tabs, frames, or iframes.